# How many arithmetic operations are required to do this polynomial division?

Tags: polynomials

$$ p(x) = q(x)j(x) + R(x) $$

$$ j(x) = x^2 + bx + c $$

How many arithmetic operations are required to the polynomial division where the second term is quadratic?

Is there a general relation to express that considering d(p) the degree of p(x) and d(j) the degree of the second?

I did some "empiric" test and I it seems that in the **worst cases** are:

```
CASE d(p) = d(j)

- #Divisions: d(j)
- #Sums = #Products = 2*d(j)

CASE d(p) > d(j)

- #Divisions: 2*d(j)
- #Sums = #Products = 2*d(j) 

CASE d(p) < d(j)

- #Divisions: 1
- #Sums = #Products = d(p)
```

Comment: depnds on the degree of $p$?

Comment: You could just count yourself by doing the divisions...or make a program...or formally prove it. So many options, but you show no effort on your part.

Comment: I tried to make some division with all the possibilities (Talking about the degree: P > D, P = D, P < D), but I can't reach a global relation that covers all the cases

Comment: The idea of considering cases is a good one.  If degree of $p$ is less than degree of $j$, then there is nothing to do; the quotient $q$ is zero and the remainder $R(x) = p(x)$.  Basically you proceed by induction.  The divisor $j(x)$ is a monic polynomial, so at each step the partial quotient will have a coefficient that agrees with the leading coefficient of the partial remainder at that step, e.g. start with the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ and subtract the corresponding multiple of $j(x)$ times $x^k$ that makes the degrees equal.